# Passing a byte* to Stream.Read(byte[], int, int)

Tags: c#, heap-memory, unsafe, stack-memory

The .NET function Stream.Read() takes a byte[] as a parameter.  Is there a way I can pass a stackalloc'd byte* instead?  This would save me from having to make an extra heap allocation and in turn save time in garbage collection.  This function is short and is repeatedly invoked.

Comment: Suggestion: don't pre-optimize. What makes you think there's a significant performance penalty for using `new byte[n]`?

Comment: No. Reuse the array instead. <!>

Comment: Because the garbage collector has to spend resources to check on it and eventually free it.  This is why stackalloc was created in the first place.  I'm working on an audio library that deals with samples of sound.  For CD audio, there are 44,100 of them each second.  This routine is going to be called quite a lot.

Comment: Make it work correctly before you make it work faster. Otherwise you're in danger of have some very fast broken code.

Comment: I was thinking of of sharing a single buffer for several different functions to use as a sandbox.  Thanks to [ThreadStatic], I believe I can.

Comment: I'm confused by your comment.  Are you saying to not make it static?  I think array reuse is the intent, but there will be several different functions making use of it.

Comment: @wswartzendruber: No, I meant that you *should* make it static, and reuse it when needed.

Comment: @wswartzendruber another option that might be safer would be using an [Array Pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't. You need to create an array and copy it into there first. See also [this thread on MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/30a79afd-95ca-425f-a8b9-fcb945f5099f).

Apart from that: I don't know the context of your application but maybe you can use a statically allocated buffer? In a multi threaded context you could allocate the buffer in the TLS like this:

```
class SomeDataProcessor
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    static byte[] _Buffer;
}
```

Note that you need to be careful with initializers though. See also [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2006/07/18/670497.aspx)

Comment: Whoa, I think we have a winner!

Answer (score -1):

I dont believe you can, but if you want to simplify the conversion. You can use:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy
```

Takes in a unmanaged address, size, byte buffer, etc